# Convert XML data to CSV String with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, osb

Consider the following XML:

```
<LIST>
    <Name>Jon</Name>
    <Name>Dan</Name>
    <Name>Bill</Name>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
</LIST>
```

I need output as a string as a CSV like `Jon,Dan,Bill,Jack` using XQuery.

I have done it using FLWOR expressions and `normalize-space` and then replacing the spaces with commas. However, I believe there should be a better way to do it in XQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `string-join` function to do this:

```
string-join(//Name/text(),",")
```

> fn:string-join($arg1 as xs:string*, $arg2 as xs:string) as xs:string
>
> Returns a xs:string created by concatenating the members of the $arg1 sequence using $arg2 as a separator.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join

Comment: `/text()` is extraneous here. See https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell.